# HTML objects not showing in the correct... order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    $('.enter_link').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('#splashscreen').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

```css
    #splashscreen {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /* bring your own prefixes */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:white;
    }
    
    #splashscreen a, h2 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /* bring your own prefixes */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="splashscreen">
     <h2>
     Hello
     </h2>
     <a href="#" class="enter_link">Enter on the website</a>
 </div>

 <div>
     <h1>Our website is so cool</h1>
     Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
 </div>
```

Now, I am a beginner in HTML, to be honest. I used the #splashscreen a, h2 CSS to put the things in the middle of the page. However, for some reason, they do not appear in the logical (my logical, atleast) order. The first thing that appears in the "enter on the website" link, and below it, "Hello". How do I fix my CSS for it to be the other way around?

Comment: How do you *want* it to look?

Comment: Note: `#splashscreen a, h2` means that the rule will apply to all `#splashscreen a` elements and all `h2` elements (not limited to ones in `#splashscreen`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As I said, how do I make it look the other way around? Therefore, first the "Hello", and then the "enter the website" link. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi, you should probably read a bit more about CSS positioning, here is a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Try adding `margin:0 auto;` to `#splashscreen{}` you shouldn't need to use `top` `left` `transform` or style the anchor tag and the header2 tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's appearing the way it is is that you've positioned both of those elements in the same location, but by default `h2` elements have a fair bit of top and bottom margin, and so that margin makes it look like the `h2` is lower down. It isn't, in fact, because again your rule puts both elements in the same place.

There are endless ways to fix it. For instance, you might remove the top margin from the `h2` and add it to the `a`:

```
#splashscreen a {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#splashscreen h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Example:

```js
$('.enter_link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('#splashscreen').fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
#splashscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#splashscreen a,
h2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#splashscreen a {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#splashscreen h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="splashscreen">
  <h2>
    Hello
  </h2>
  <a href="#" class="enter_link">Enter on the website</a>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Our website is so cool</h1>
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

...but again, that's just one of lots of different options, depending on your overall goal

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that h2 elements had a bit of top and bottom margin, so I guess that I'm set for the future when this problem appears again. Once again, thank you very much, I'm accepting this answer as soon as I can!

Comment: @CarlosMenezes: Happy to help. FYI (you said you're new to this stuff), a great way to see what's going on is to right-click the element and choose "Inspect element" (the exact menu item varies between Chrome, Firefox, and IE/Edge, but it's along those lines). That will open devtools and navigate to the element. Usually there's then somewhere you can see exactly what parts of the element are where. That's how I figured out it was margin...

Answer (score 1):

Both of your elements are in the center of the page, but because of position FIXED, they overlap. If you inspect the h2 element (press F12 for developer tools) you will see it has a a top and bottom margin. 
This invisible distance basicaly pushes it bellow the link (it is centered in the middle of the page, but is bigger than you see it)

If you add

```
h2{
    margin: 0;
}
```

You will notice that both elements overlap.

I highly recommend to redo the code avoiding fixed position. Leave this type of value alone for the moment.

A simple form of code to what you need is:

```js
    $('.enter_link').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('#splashscreen').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

```css
    #splashscreen {
        background-color:white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    #splashscreen h2 {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="splashscreen">
     <h2>
     Hello
     </h2>
     <a href="#" class="enter_link">Enter on the website</a>
 </div>

 <div>
     <h1>Our website is so cool</h1>
     Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
 </div>
```